# Converting the Web API controller to use the Models instead of direct database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

We created the Web API for querying the Oracle DB and returns result in JSON format. The Web API accepts array of two input parameters, one is the Array of column names that needs to be selected and the other is the array of ID which is used in the WHERE clause. SQL statement in our case is very complex using various tables and various joins so I am just giving a simple Select here instead of the huge complex SQL statement.

The Controller looks like below

```
namespace PSData.Controllers
{
public class PDController : ApiController
{
public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails([FromUri] string[] id, [FromUri] string[] Column)
{           
   List<OracleParameter> prms = new List<OracleParameter>();
   List<string> selectionStrings = new List<string>();
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PDConnection"].ConnectionString;
    using (OracleConnection dbconn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
    {
        var inconditions = id.Distinct().ToArray();
        var srtcon = string.Join(",", inconditions);
        DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
        var colDict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
        {"CATEGORY", "STPR_STD_ANML.DESCR"},
        {"SESSION_NUMBER", "STPR_STD_ANML.SESSION_NUM"},
        {"SESSION_START_DATE","Trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE)"}
        };
        foreach (string col in Column)
        {
            string selector = colDict[col];
            selectionStrings.Add(string.Format("{0} AS {1}", selector, col));
        }
        string selectString = string.Join(",", selectionStrings);

        var strQuery =   string.Format(@"SELECT DISTINCT {0}
                         FROM 
                         STPR_STD_ANML WHERE
                         STPR_STUDY.STPR_STD_ANML(", selectString);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(strQuery);
            for (int x = 0; x < inconditions.Length; x++)
            {
                sb.Append(":p" + x + ",");
                OracleParameter p = new OracleParameter(":p" + x, OracleDbType.NVarchar2);
                p.Value = inconditions[x];
                prms.Add(p);
            }
            if (sb.Length > 0) sb.Length--;
            strQuery = sb.ToString() + ")";
            using (OracleCommand selectCommand = new OracleCommand(strQuery, dbconn))
            {
                selectCommand.Parameters.AddRange(prms.ToArray());
                using (OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(selectCommand))
                {
                    DataTable selectResults = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(selectResults);
                    var returnObject = new { data = selectResults };
                    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnObject, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
                    ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
                    if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=PSData.json", out contentDisposition))
                    {
                        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
                    }
                    return response;
                }
}}}}
```

Since we are having issue serialize the response body and get the error like 
`"The 'ObjectContent1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'."`
So I am trying to incoperate the Models and DB Context in to the Application. I tried to both like

```
namespace PSData.Models
{
public class StudyDataModel
{

    [Key]
    public string CATEGORY { get; set; }
    public int SESSION_NUMBER { get; set; }
    public DateTime SESSION_START_DATE { get; set; }
   }}
```

And the DB Context

```
 namespace PSData.Models
{
 public class StudyDataContext:DbContext

{
    public DbSet<StudyDataModel> details { get; set; }
}}
```

I am not sure how to make use of this Models and DBContext in to Controller instead of dealing directly dealing with the Database. This is my 1st .NET application and kind of little stuck. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *The Web API accepts array of two input parameters, one is the Array of column names tthat needs to be selected and the other is the array of ID which is used in the WHERE clause.*  At this point, it may just be easier to allow the your API to take SQL statement to be executed.

Comment: visual studio has the function to reverse get models (as c#-code) from database: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application then you can write controllers with repositories. take a look at here: http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/08/10/creating-an-asp-net-web-api-using-the-entity-framework-code-first-approach-and-the-repository-pattern.aspx

Comment: @MaxSorin The SQL is very complex, I have just given the sample Select statement here. So we cannot give the SQL statement directly in the API

Comment: @MatthiasBurger The SQL is very complex which deals with the various table uses various joins(here in the code I just gave the sample select statement). So it was not was not possible for us to create the Entity Data Model

Comment: Break the problem into parts. 1) How to couple EF with your existing database (ie. defining a model based on your relevant schema). 2) How to query that EF model. 3) Returning the expected results. Your problem is not special or unique in any way that I can see, it is fairly generic and has been done many times before (this is a good thing). Follow some tutorials starting with EF database first and then move on to the web api part once you get the first part working. I would also suggest wrapping your EF access in its own class for better SoC.

Comment: Also many times its easier to map a VIEW to a model (*instead of mapping the tables directly and rebuilding a large statement in c# code*) and this is probably the case here.

Comment: @Igor I have added the actual Select statement in the question. The issue was we were not able to select the few of the tables in the Where Caluse. So had to go with this approach. Is there any without using the Entity Data Model

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking? Can you take the whole statement and convert it to a VIEW and then model/map that View in EF. Include the columns used in the WHERE clause in the VIEW/Model and filter on that in c#.

Comment: @Igor We just have the read only access to the DB and will not be able to create a View

Comment: I am new to .NET and the C# programming, may be I am not getting it

Comment: build a model that matches your statement, and then call it with `IEnumerable<Model> result = myContext.Database.SqlQuery<Model>("select * from anything").ToList();`

Comment: Also this error occurs only when I deploy in the TEST server. In the DEV server it works perfectly

Comment: so maybe check for differences of your database first. Settings/columns/datatypes of columns/...

Comment: @MatthiasBurger I am connecting to the same DB which I connected from the DEV server. Both servers have access to the same database.

Comment: So check your server-settings. Any differences must exist..